# What is the best way to load profile data in Flutter using Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout

I am attempting to load profile data using Firestore. I do not want to reload data every time that I click on the homepage.

I want to store this data in the class object, then have a refresh function that the use can manually call after the first initialization of the profile data. I thought of doing this on the call to the "HomePage" widget passing in the snapshot of my "ProfileModel", but will it continuously load this data in the same manner?

**This is my nav bar widget class that is called for the selected index**

```
  class SelectedNavigationBarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  FirebaseAuth auth;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  final int currentIndex;
  bool hasBeenWelcomed = false;
  @override
  SelectedNavigationBarItem(
      {@required this.auth, @required this.firestore, this.currentIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      HomeBarWelcome(
          auth: this.auth,
          firestore: this.firestore,
          welcomed: hasBeenWelcomed),
      Text("PlaceHolder1"),
      Text("Placeholder2"),
      Text("Placeholder3"),
    ];
    return _widgetOptions.elementAt(this.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

I was thinking of a way of using a FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder to pass in the profile data snapshot to the HomePage class I have. Then from there, I would pass that snapshot down the widget tree, but if I do that in my very first widget the one called by runApp(), will it continuously load the profile data and keep making calls to Firestore for the profile data?
Or will it be ran once, and sit in the HomePage class that would be returned within that first runApp() call?

**I guess I am just kind of asking how the widgets are called?** Is runApp() being continuously called and then it traverses down the widget path each call? Or is it called once and from there the Widget classes handle the state of the Flutter application, and each Widget class takes control of the state depending on the next widget called in that Widget class?
Sorry, I am sure that this was a pretty confusing post. But I am just looking for the proper way to load this data, as I don't want repetitive calls to Firestore fetching data unnecessarily.

Comment: You must change your strategy from `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget` and in `initState` part of your `State` class load the resource and store it to a field....

Comment: @Nima I am already doing that, but I do not want to reload my profile and call to firestore on each call to the state change. I want to the profile to be loaded once and only once, then refreshed on a manual call to refresh data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in my Authentication wrapper called by my MaterialApp, I used a StreamBuilder with nested FutureBuilders to resolve my issues. After this I just passed down the variable through my widget trees.

I feels as if there is a better way of doing this, but I don't have the answer yet. So I will be using this, as it works.

**Here is my _AuthWrapperState class:**

```
class _AuthWrapperState extends State<AuthenticationWrapper> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<ProfileModel> _getProfile() async {
    return await Database(_firestore).getProfile(uid: _auth.currentUser.uid);
  }

  Future<SharedPreferences> _getPrefs() async {
    return await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: AuthService(auth: _auth, firestore: _firestore).user,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          if (snapshot.data?.uid == null) {
            return SignIn(auth: _auth, firestore: _firestore);
          } else {
            return FutureBuilder(
                future: _getProfile(),
                builder: (builder, AsyncSnapshot<ProfileModel> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    ProfileModel profileModel = snapshot.data;
                    return FutureBuilder(
                        future: _getPrefs(),
                        builder: (context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Home(
                              auth: _auth,
                              firestore: _firestore,
                              profileModel: profileModel,
                              sharedPrefs: snapshot.data,
                            );
                          } else {
                            return const Scaffold(
                              body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            );
                          }
                        });
                  } else {
                    return const Scaffold(
                        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
                  }
                });
          }
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Loading..."),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a navigation bar, maybe you might want to load your data in initState function. This will let your data load once the navigation bar is built. In order to use it, convert your Stateless widget into a Stateful widget first. It should be placed above `build ()`. Here is how it looks:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // load your data here
    super.initState();
  }
```

The data will load once and you can bring it down to your Navigation Bar Items. I hope this helped!